# The type String from the descriptor computed for the target context is not visible here for property in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I keep getting `The type String from the descriptor computed for the target context is not visible here.` errors when I try to update a TableColumn like so:

```
deleteColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().websiteProperty());
keepColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().websiteProperty());
```

Rest of controller class:

```
public class WebsiteOverviewController {

    // Instance variables cut out 

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        deleteColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().websiteProperty());
        keepColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().websiteProperty());


    }

    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;

        keepData = new FilteredList<>(mainApp.getWebsiteData(), p -> p.getKeep());
        deleteData = new FilteredList<>(mainApp.getWebsiteData(), p -> p.getDelete());
        deleteTable.setItems(deleteData);
        keepTable.setItems(keepData);

        scanButton.visibleProperty().bind(isScanning.not());
        pauseButton.visibleProperty().bind(isScanning);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mainApp.handleScanInbox(paused);
            }

        });
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

I'm really baffled as to why this is the case. Any ideas why this is?

Thanks!!

**EDIT:**

Tables and columns:

```
    @FXML
    private TableView<Website> deleteTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Website, String> deleteColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Website> keepTable;

    @FXML 
    private TableColumn<Website, String> keepColumn;
```

Website class:

```
    private final StringProperty website;
    private final BooleanProperty accountExists;
    private final BooleanProperty keep;
    private final BooleanProperty delete;
```

Comment: Could you show the type of the table items (including the `website` property and the class visibility/supertypes at least).

Comment: made an edit with the info

Comment: What's the visibility of `websiteProperty()` and the `Website` class? Are both `Website` and `WebsiteOverviewController` in the same package (assuming one of the visibilities are package private)?

Comment: both public and both in separate packages